# Centre image in a DIV

Tags: css, html

There are numerous discussionsn on SO but I've tried suggestions without success. I have a DIV within which I need an image, whose height and width are unknown, to be centered horizontally and vertically.

I also need this multiple times so I don't want to have to add more CSS code each time.

Here's what I have in terms of CSS and HTML for the DIV.

```
.gallery_image_container {
    position: relative;
    width: 830px;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 7;
    border: solid 4px #EAEAEA;
    background-image:url(bottom_back.png);
}
```

and

```
<div class="gallery_image_container">
<img src="image.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: `xposition` must be one of those new CSS7 properties.

Comment: I think you have a typo, `xposition` doesn't exist, try `position`.

Comment: You could always go to the dark side and use a table element to host the image instead of a div.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid tables, haha. Although it's ironic that it's so easy to do in a table structure.

Comment: If you don't know the size of image, it could be hard with only css but if you use javascript for it could be easy

Comment: And the page would look funky with javascript disabled.  I don't think it's a good idea in general to rely on javascript for layout work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give credit, I reviewed this very helpful article: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

You need to add 3 more CSS rules to `.gallery_image_container`:

```
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

The first line is pretty obvious; it gets you centered horizontally.
The second line gets your div to behave in a table cell-like manner, and the third makes the vertical alignment happen.  I'd post a jsfiddle to demonstrate but they are doing some maintenance stuff today.  I did test it and it worked in current Chrome and FF and IE 8.

Comment: +1 I'm faced with this exact problem and I'm now referring to your accepted answer and not my wrong one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using css directly you can include the image into the div tag and you can make it centralised and no need of adding img tag inside of div and making it centerlised and also you can observe main div has control over image using css

```
<div class="right-panel"></div>

.right-panel{
height: 25%;    
width: 50px;    
background: url(/assets/image-png/rightPanel_3.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px;
background-size: 48px 64px;
 }
```

Comment: how this code snippet relates to the question? it's out the context totally.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".