# Centre an Image

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to horizontally center an image. However it does not move from the left side of the page. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217131/centre-image-in-a-div) does not work in my case. What am I doing wrong?

```
#container {                
        width: 100%;        
        border: 2px yellow dashed;
        height: 100px;
}

#profile-image img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 2px orange solid;
}
```

mypage:

```
<div id="container">
            <div id="profile-image">
                <p><img src="<?php echo $data['profile_image_url'];?>" alt="me"></p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make any div or anything horizontally at center , common css approach will be,lets have a width and declare `margin:0 auto;`

```
#profile-image{
  width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: although the problem with this approach is you have to explicitly assign a width to the container..

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rua4d/2/

```
#container {                
    width: 300px;        
    border: 2px yellow dashed;
    height: 100px;
    display:table-cell;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
}


#profile-image img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 2px orange solid;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    width:50px;
}
```

Comment: Why `vertical-align: middle;` on a block element?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add

```
display:block
```

to your image's style. Images are inline elements, and inline elements ignore margins.

Answer (score 1):

why cant this work?

```
#profile-image p { text-align: center; }
#profile-image img { display: inline; }
```

that way you won't need to specify the width.. if you want margins to work together with the `text-align: center` you would need `inline-block` instead:

```
#profile-image p { text-align: center; }
#profile-image img { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: +1 Yes! This is excellent! Although @RitabrataGautam's example worked for my image (the size of this image will never change - its 48px by 48px) my text below the image will change in length and your solution worked perfectly! Thank you soo much!

Comment: no problem. <img> elements are inline by default.. so you can `text-align: center` them.. i concluded that you needed the width,etc and to make them work you made them as `block`, but that would cancel out the text-align property.. so what you really need for the image is the `display: inline-block` which has both.

Comment: and i only use `margin: 0 auto;` when I am sure that the container would have a user-defined with.. like for the outermost wrapper element for example.